# Using ansible to reboot a remote host that does not have python installed

Tags: ansible

My organization has tasked me with finding out a way to use Ansible to automate rebooting some of our cctv cameras, as we currently use it for a lot of our other infrastructure

The cameras (Axis) are running armv7l GNU/Linux with some proprietary stuff built on top, however python is not installed and after doing quite a bit of research and reaching out to the vendor there is no "official" way of installing python without something else breaking.

That being said, I have looked around and have come across of two Ansible modules that could potentially do this, `raw` and `script`. All that needs to be done is to reboot these cameras.

However, I am now completely lost in finding a solution to my issue. Below is my current playbook and output.

```yaml
- name: cctv restart playbook
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no  
  tasks:
  - name: restart cctv
    raw:
      cmd: reboot
```

The output from when I run this playbook is

```
PLAY [cctv restart playbook] ***************************************************************************************************************

TASK [restart cctv] ************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.10.130]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.10.130 closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to 192.168.10.130 closed."], "stdout": "sh: None: not found\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["sh: None: not found"]}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.10.130             : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Please let me know what needs to be done to fix this, or if it is just not possible

Comment: Ansible uses `sh` as a shell by default, which is not available on your cctv device. Find out which shell should be used then change it in the [relevant option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/raw_module.html#parameter-executable)

Comment: Whereby the module `raw` "_... is useful and should only be done in a few cases. ... Another is speaking to any devices such as routers that do not have any Python installed._" you'll probably need to focus on the given comment regarding the remote shell `sh`. Furthermore, I wasn't able to find enough information or details regarding your camera if it has an SSH server and if there is shell with a `reboot` command. A search comes up with different approaches of rebooting via FTP, `curl` and HTTPS and .cgi, or `/sbin/reboot`. Because of the lack of information no further hint can be provided.

Comment: I think we can be reasonably confident that a device "running armv7l GNU/Linux" has `/bin/sh`. In any case, the immediate issue is a syntax error in the playbook, which once corrected will be followed by a connection error. We can resolve both of these and come up with a working solution.

Answer (score 3):

While the comments on your question are partly correct, the immediate source of your error message appears to be a syntax issue. The `raw` command does not support a `cmd` parameter; even targeting a regular Linux system, a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: restart cctv
      raw:
        cmd: "date"
```

Results in the same error:

```
fatal: [node0]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg":
"non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "stderr": "Warning:
Permanently added 'localhost' (ED25519) to the list of
known hosts.\r\nShared connection to localhost
closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Warning: Permanently added
'localhost' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.",
"Shared connection to localhost closed."], "stdout":
"bash: None: command not found\r\n", "stdout_lines":
["bash: None: command not found"]}
```

Which, stripped of all the extranneous bits, reads:

```
bash: None: command not found
```

(This is at least true for Ansible core 2.14.1, which is what I'm running, and that matches [the documentation for the `raw` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/raw_module.html#examples).)

You need to write your task like this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: restart cctv
      raw: "date"
```

As @Zeitounator said in their comment, for this to work, your remote device needs to be at least a minimal Linux-like environment with a `sh` command. Assuming that you have this, you would still expect to see an error when attempting to run the `reboot` command, because that causes the connection to drop. That would look something like this:

```
fatal: [node0]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg":
"Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection
to node0.virt closed.", "unreachable": true}
```

Since you know that's going to result in an error, you can tell Ansible to ignore the failure. For example:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: restart cctv
      raw: "reboot"
      ignore_unreachable: true
```

Running this playbook results in:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************

TASK [restart cctv] *************************************************************************************
fatal: [node0]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to node0.virt closed.", "unreachable": true}
...ignoring

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************
node0                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

(And the target system reboots.)

Comment: Hey, -1 voter; can you let me know how I can improve this answer? I think it correctly addresses the question and results in a working solution. I thought it was a pretty good answer!